# Number of elements remains the same after appending with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I am creating a notes list, that lets you add a note from an input value.

Under the notes list `ul`, it displays a message saying the number of notes. `($('li').length)`.

However, if you add a new note to the list, the number of notes remains the same. It doesn't update when you add a new note or if you clear all notes by removing all the lies in the list.

I tried creating a function that displays the number of notes and added it as a call back function after the `addNote` and `clearNote` function but it still only displays the amount of `li`'s that are in the original HTML. (3li's).

How can I update this so that it adds one when an li is added?

```
//    N° of notes length
let numberOfNotes = $('li').length;
//   End  N° of notes length

NotesNumberMessage()

// Display N° of notes length
function NotesNumberMessage() {
    $('#NumberPostMessage').text(`You have ${numberOfNotes} active notes`);
};
// End display N° of notes length

// Add a new note function
function addNote() {
    $('#addBtn').on('click', function () {
        let noteText = ($('#input').val());
        let newTodo = $('<li class="list-group-item" id="note"></li>').text(noteText);
        $('#noteList').append(newTodo);
    });
    NotesNumberMessage()
    alert(numberOfNotes);
};
// End add a new note function
```

Comment: You're never updating the `numberOfNotes` variable, which is a number.  And has no reference to how that number was derrived.

Comment: don't use the variable `numberOfNotes` instead use `$('li').length` each time you need to get the actual number, or maybe update the `numberOfNotes` each time before you use it

Comment: You can implement your logic and can break into functions. Created an example for you: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEBvxL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the `numberOfNotes` variable once and never updated it.

What you should do is update the variable inside the `NotesNumberMessage` function. And remove it from the global declaration if you don't need it anywhere else.

```
//    N° of notes length
let numberOfNotes = $('li').length; // can be removed;
//   End  N° of notes length

NotesNumberMessage()

// Display N° of notes length
function NotesNumberMessage() {
    // N° of notes length
    let numberOfNotes = $('li').length;
    $('#NumberPostMessage').text(`You have ${numberOfNotes} active notes`);
};
// End display N° of notes length
```

While you're testing the number of lists,

```
alert(numberOfNotes);
```

update the variable like below and then alert:

```
numberOfNotes = $('li').length;
alert(numberOfNotes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @MaxPauwels if it helped / solved your problem, feel free to upvote and accept the answer. it's a Stackoverflow good practice

Comment: Hi Towkir! Yup, I tried this but it's not allowing me to upvote! It tells me that votes from accounts with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but not displayed publicly...

Comment: ah, it's because you don't have enough reputation maybe. you can still accept the answer. there is a tick mark there.

Comment: Just did! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

If you store a reference to the `ul/ol` you are adding the `li` to, you can get the `.children().length` each time for an up to date count.

You should also do your `NotesNumberMessage()` call inside the click handler, otherwise it would never happen after the first call to `addNode()`, which **should only be called once** as it is creating an event binding.

```
let $noteList = $('#noteList');

NotesNumberMessage();

function NotesNumberMessage() {
    $('#NumberPostMessage').text(`You have ${$noteList.children().length} active notes`);
};

function addNote() {
    $('#addBtn').on('click', function () {
        let noteText = $('#input').val();
        let newTodo = $('<li class="list-group-item" class="note"></li>').text(noteText);
        $noteList.append(newTodo);

        NotesNumberMessage();
        alert($noteList.children().length);
    });
};
```